# Tailwind Play cdn not working in normal html file

Tags: javascript, html, tailwind-css

I was working with tailwind, js and html a day before. It was working fine, but suddenly from today the tailwind is not getting applied to my html file.
I also tried reaching the src file that is https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/ this, but it says there's a typo mistake.
What to do >

Comment: It seems like I can reach the file now. Maybe the server was down while you tried to use it? Or maybe your DNS provider have somehow managed to lose the IP connected to `cdn.tailwindcss.com`

First, see if you are able to access the file now. If you are still not able to access the file, try to change your DNS settings to googles DNS `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` and see if you then are able to access the file

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue a few days ago. I tried changing my DNS to Google DNS and it worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).